# react router and redux dispatch() is running from all routes once instead of only current route

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router-v4

I am new to `react` and building an app using `react-router-dom@v4` and `react-redux`.

The **App** component looks like as:

```
    <Router>
        <Grid container>
            <Grid item xs={12}>
                <Header/>
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={12}>
                <Route exact path="/" component={Dashboard}/>
                <Route path="/admin" component={Admin}/>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </Router>
```

and the **Root** file is rendering as:

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <App />
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('root'));
```

**Now the problem is:**

1. Both routes contains same `store.dispatch` with different values as:
2. The first route `/`

   ```
    store.dispatch({type: "active": payload: 1})
   ```
3. The second route `/admin`

   ```
    store.dispatch({type: "active": payload: 0})
   ```

Now when the application runs on the index route `/` it runs `dispatch()` and gives value `1`... correct.
but afterward It also run the `dispatch()` from the other route `/admin` and updates the value to `0`... which I don't want..

**What I want:**

That application should run `dispatch()` when I'm on that route not once from all routes.

any help would be appreciated:

:)

cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At last, I have found the answer to this question that how to avoid the problem that running `dispatch()` once from all routes.

Simply put the `store.dispatch()` in the lifecycle hook of the ReactJS Component like putting in `componentDidMount()` would work and it would only call when a user is on that Component/route.

Here is an example below:

```
componentDidMount() {
    store.dispatch({type: "active", payload: 0});
}
```